# How to use the output of RowMatrix.columnSimilarities

Tags: java, scala, matrix, apache-spark, sparse-matrix

I need to compute similarities between columns of a row and tried columnsimilarities() method to get results.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    SparkConf sparkConf = new SparkConf().setAppName("CollarberativeFilter").setMaster("local");
        JavaSparkContext sc = new JavaSparkContext(sparkConf);
        SparkSession spark = SparkSession.builder().appName("CollarberativeFilter").getOrCreate();
        double[][] array = {{5,0,5}, {0,10,0}, {5,0,5}};
        LinkedList<Vector> rowsList = new LinkedList<Vector>();
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
          Vector currentRow = Vectors.dense(array[i]);
          rowsList.add(currentRow);
        }
        JavaRDD<Vector> rows = sc.parallelize(rowsList);

        // Create a RowMatrix from JavaRDD<Vector>.
        RowMatrix mat = new RowMatrix(rows.rdd());
         CoordinateMatrix simsPerfect = mat.columnSimilarities();
         RowMatrix mat2 = simsPerfect.toRowMatrix();
         List<Vector> vs2 = mat2.rows().toJavaRDD().collect();
         List<Vector> vs = mat.rows().toJavaRDD().collect();
         System.out.println("mat");
         for(Vector v: vs) {
             System.out.println(v);
         }
         System.out.println("mat2");
         for(Vector v: vs2) {
             System.out.println(v);
         }
         JavaRDD<MatrixEntry> entries = simsPerfect.entries().toJavaRDD();
         JavaRDD<String> output = entries.map(new Function<MatrixEntry, String>() {
             public String call(MatrixEntry e) {
                 return String.format("%d,%d,%s", e.i(), e.j(), e.value());
             }
         });
         output.saveAsTextFile("resources123/data.txt");

}
```

But the

> output in the text file was 0,2,0.9999999999999998

.

Next I tried the same example using `double[][] array = {{1,3}, {2,7}};`
Then the

> output of the text file was 0,1,0.9982743731749959

Can someone explain me the answer format.Can't I get a score for each and every column pair of the matrix.Such as in 3 by 3 matrix I need 3 scores for similarity between 1,2 columns , 2,3 columns , 3,1 columns.
Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Column Similarity is computed with the [Cosine Similarity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cosine_similarity) defined as follows:

[image: Cosine Similarity]

Since you included the `scala` tag I am going to cheat and repeat what you did in the Scala REPL:

```scala
scala> import org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.{Vectors, Vector}
import org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.{Vectors, Vector}

scala> import org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.distributed.RowMatrix
import org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.distributed.RowMatrix

scala> val matVec = Vector(Vectors.dense(5,0,5), Vectors.dense(0,10,0), Vectors.dense(5,0,5))
matVec: scala.collection.immutable.Vector[org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.Vector] = Vector([5.0,0.0,5.0], [0.0,10.0,0.0], [5.0,0.0,5.0])

scala> val matRDD = sc.parallelize(matVec)
matRDD: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.Vector] = ParallelCollectionRDD[44] at parallelize at <console>:37

scala> val myRowMat = new RowMatrix(matRDD)
myRowMat: org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.distributed.RowMatrix = org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.distributed.RowMatrix@7a7a07c2

scala> myRowMat.columnSimilarities.entries.collect.foreach{println}
MatrixEntry(0,2,0.9999999999999998)
```

This output means that there was only one nonzero entry at (`row0`, `col2`). Thus the actual (upper triangular) output was:

```
0    0    .9999
0    0    0
0    0    0
```

Which is what you would expect (since the dot product between `col0` and `col1` is zero and the dot product between `col1` and `col2` is zero)

Here is an example with a less sparse column similarities matrix:

```
scala> def randVec(len: Int) : org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.Vector =
     | Vectors.dense(Array.fill(len)(Random.nextDouble))
randVec: (len: Int)org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.Vector

scala> val randRDD = sc.parallelize(Seq.fill(3)(randVec(4))
randRDD: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.Vector] = ParallelCollectionRDD[123] at parallelize at <console>:38

scala> val randRowMat = new RowMatrix(randRDD)
randRowMat: org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.distributed.RowMatrix = org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.distributed.RowMatrix@77d9112e

scala> randRowMat.rows.collect.foreach{println}
[0.11049508671100228,0.6560383649078886,0.08647831963379027,0.918734774579884]
[0.5709766390994561,0.5404121150599919,0.8206115742925799,0.12848224469499103]
[0.5414651842028494,0.26273347471310016,0.3139446375461201,0.351113866208812]

scala> randRowMat.columnSimilarities.entries.collect.foreach{println}
MatrixEntry(0,3,0.4630854334046888)
MatrixEntry(0,2,0.9238294198864545)
MatrixEntry(2,3,0.33700154742702093)
MatrixEntry(0,1,0.7402725425024911)
MatrixEntry(1,2,0.7418690274112878)
MatrixEntry(1,3,0.8662504236158493)
```

Which represents the following matrix:

```
0       0.74027     0.92382     0.46308
0       0           0.74186     0.86625
0       0           0           0.33700
0       0           0           0
```

Comment: Thank you very much for clarifying this. Can I know whether it is possible to use datasets for computations instead of RDDs. According to my knowledge ColumnSimilarity algorithm is not yet moved to use datasets.

Comment: My understanding is that `Dataset`s are here to replace `Dataframe`s, not `RDD`s since they have different underlying implementations with different use cases. Check [this article](https://databricks.com/blog/2016/07/14/a-tale-of-three-apache-spark-apis-rdds-dataframes-and-datasets.html) out for a primer on the differences.

Comment: Thank you very much.I ll check this.

Comment: Thanks evan.oman for the detailed response . It helped a lot to improve my understanding of the CoordinateMatrix .  In the output of your second example with sparse column , how can we know the similarity between rows  0 and 1 , 1 and 2 etc ?